# How to delete Dyld's Shared Cache on High Sierra?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, macos-high-sierra, dyld, darwin

I'd like to delete the DYLD's Shared Cache located at `/private/var/db/dyld` on High Sierra Mac machines for analysis of an issue. It's not recommended to delete it manually.

The [man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/update_dyld_shared_cache/) of `update_dyld_shared_cache` command mentions that the cache should be deleted if a safe-boot is done. However, it is not being deleted (nor freshly created) even when I perform safe-boot on few High Sierra machines.

Is there a way to somehow delete it or make the safe-boot solution work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Onyx, it is free. It will clean the shared cache.